# Performing jQuery only when all fields are full, or changed after load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a simple calculator with jQuery, that works but it only works on page load. I have it setup so that it checks if there are values in the inputs..

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){ ...variables...

if (noProp != null && noTimesInsp != null && timeCompile != null && rateManager != null)
calculations..
```

Then it performs the necessary calculations. My question being, is it possible to re-run the calculations when one of the 4 inputs are changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach a `change` event handler to the inputs.

This will make sure your code will run when any of the inputs change their value.

```
$('input[type=text]').on('change', function() {
     // Your code
});
```

If the `inputs are of type text`,  otherwise this selector should do `$('input')`

Answer (score 0):

To check for changes to any input:

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type="number"]').change(function() {
     // an input has changed
});
```

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

this do calculations when each input text is changing

```
$('input[type=text]').change(function() {
       calculations ...
});
```