# Is it possible for change function to fire more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a dynamic form that re-calculates values every time one of the 4 input fields are changed. So far..

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){ ...variables...
```

Then I have..

```
jQuery('.changeCalc').change(function()
{
    calculations();
});
```

I am using the change function to re-perform the calculations function that I have created. The issue is, when I test this, I change any one of the four fields and it performs the `calculations()` function. The problem: it only does it one time per page load. Is it possible  to change this so it fires multiple times?

Relevant HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="managed_properties" id="managed_properties" class="changeCalc"     required />
<input type="text" name="inspections_peryr" id="inspections_peryr" value="" class="changeCalc" required />
<select name="time_reports" id="time_reports" class="changeCalc" required>
  <option value="20">20 minutes</option>
  <option value="30">30 minutes</option>
  <option value="45">45 minutes</option>
  <option value="1">1 hour</option>
  <option value="2">2 hours</option>
</select>
<select name="prop_managers" id="prop_managers" class="changeCalc" required>
  <option value="15">$15</option>
  <option value="20">$20</option>
  <option value="25">$25</option>
  <option value="30">$30</option>
  <option value="40">$40</option>
  <option value="50">$50</option>
</select>
```

Edit: The answers so far haven't worked, so maybe showing the calculations function could shed some light on the true issue here..

```
calculations = function()
{

//Perform the calculations
if (noProp != null && noTimesInsp != null && timeCompile != null && rateManager != null)
{
// Step 2 per year
saveHrYr = timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp);
saveDollarYr = ((rateManager * (timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp))) * (noProp * .17))
ROI = ((rateManager * (timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp))) / ((noProp * .17)*12))
//Display the answer
var displaySaveHrYr = document.getElementById('snapSvHrYr');
jQuery('#snapSvHrYr').empty();
displaySaveHrYr.innerHTML = displaySaveHrYr.innerHTML + saveHrYr.toFixed(0);
var displaySaveDollarYr = document.getElementById('snapSvDollarYr');
jQuery('#snapSvDollarYr').empty();
displaySaveDollarYr.innerHTML = displaySaveDollarYr.innerHTML + saveDollarYr.toFixed(0);
var displayROI = document.getElementById('backPerDollar');
jQuery('#backPerDollar').empty();
displayROI.innerHTML = displayROI.innerHTML + ROI.toFixed(0);
// Step 2 per month
saveHrMth = (timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp)/12);
saveDollarMth = ((rateManager * (timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp))) * (noProp * .17))/12
var displaySaveHrMth = document.getElementById('snapSvHrMth');
jQuery('#snapSvHrMth').empty();
displaySaveHrMth.innerHTML = displaySaveHrMth.innerHTML + saveHrMth.toFixed(0);
var displaySaveDollarMth = document.getElementById('snapSvDollarMth');
jQuery('#snapSvDollarMth').empty();
displaySaveDollarMth.innerHTML = displaySaveDollarMth.innerHTML + saveDollarMth.toFixed(0);
//SnapInspect cost per yr/mth
snapCostMth = noProp * .17
snapCostYr = snapCostMth * 12
var displaySnapCostYr = document.getElementById('snapCostYr');
jQuery('#snapCostYr').empty();
displaySnapCostYr.innerHTML = displaySnapCostYr.innerHTML + snapCostYr.toFixed(0);
var displaySnapCostMth = document.getElementById('snapCostMth');
jQuery('#snapCostMth').empty();
displaySnapCostMth.innerHTML = displaySnapCostMth.innerHTML + snapCostMth.toFixed(0);
}
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by multiple times ? is it on a certain event ?

Comment: For validation per form field you typically use the `blur` event instead of `change`

Comment: I adjusted my code to include `blur` instead of `change` however, the issue is the same. Also @karthikr I mean I want to know if it can perform the calculations function every time any one of the four fields is changed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performing jQuery only when all fields are full, or changed after load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992740/performing-jquery-only-when-all-fields-are-full-or-changed-after-load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do something like this :

```
$(function() {
    var calc = function () {
        //perform calculations here
    };
    $('input.changeCalc').on('blur', calc);
    $('select.changeCalc').on('change', calc).eq(0).trigger('blur');
});
```

### EDIT ...

The most likely thing that's preventing the calculations bing performed multiple times is the `if(noProp ...)` condition.

You need to be aware that in javasacript `foo != null` is the same as `foo != 0`. Hence if any of the variables `noProp`, `noTimesInsp`, `timeCompile` or `rateManager` is zero, then the calcs will not be performed.

In order to take variable *type* into accounnt you have to test with `===` or `!==`.

Applying `!==` and further leveraging jQuery yields  the following :

```
var calc = function() {
    if(noProp !== null && noTimesInsp !== null && timeCompile !== null && rateManager !== null) {
        var saveHrYr = timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp);
        var saveDollarYr = ((rateManager * (timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp))) * (noProp * .17));
        var ROI = ((rateManager * (timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp))) / ((noProp * .17) * 12));
        jQuery('#snapSvHrYr').text(saveHrYr.toFixed(0));
        jQuery('#snapSvDollarYr').text(saveDollarYr.toFixed(0));
        jQuery('#backPerDollar').text(ROI.toFixed(0));

        var saveHrMth = (timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp)/12);
        var saveDollarMth = ((rateManager * (timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp))) * (noProp * .17))/12;
        jQuery('#snapSvHrMth').text(saveHrMth.toFixed(0));
        jQuery('#snapSvDollarMth').text(saveDollarMth.toFixed(0));

        var snapCostMth = noProp * .17;
        var snapCostYr = snapCostMth * 12;
        jQuery('#snapCostYr').text(snapCostYr.toFixed(0));
        jQuery('#snapCostMth').text(snapCostMth.toFixed(0));
    }
};
```

If you still get the same problem then some other piece of code must be detaching the event handlers.

### EDIT 2

Here's the code with the four "val" statements moved inside `calculations()` :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var calculations = function() {
        var noProp = parseInt($('#managed_properties').val()) || 0;
        var noTimesInsp = parseInt($('#inspections_peryr').val()) || 0;
        var timeCompile = $('#time_reports').val();
        var rateManager = $('#prop_managers').val();

        var saveHrYr = timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp);
        var saveDollarYr = ((rateManager * (timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp))) * (noProp * .17))
        var ROI = ((rateManager * (timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp))) / ((noProp * .17)*12))
        $('#snapSvHrYr').text(saveHrYr.toFixed(0));
        $('#snapSvDollarYr').text(saveDollarYr.toFixed(0));
        $('#backPerDollar').text(ROI.toFixed(0));

        var saveHrMth = (timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp)/12);
        var saveDollarMth = ((rateManager * (timeCompile * (noProp * noTimesInsp))) * (noProp * .17))/12
        $('#snapSvHrMth').text(saveHrMth.toFixed(0));
        $('#snapSvDollarMth').text(saveDollarMth.toFixed(0));

        var snapCostMth = noProp * .17
        var snapCostYr = snapCostMth * 12
        $('#snapCostYr').text(snapCostYr.toFixed(0));
        $('#snapCostMth').text(snapCostMth.toFixed(0));
    };
    $('input.changeCalc').on('blur', calculations);
    $('select.changeCalc').on('change', calculations).eq(0).trigger('blur');
});
```

Comment: I've tried this way, and the other answer's way. Still getting the exact same issue. The fields will be set once, and changing the fields does not change them again.

Comment: I appreciate your help with this, I tried the code you submitted, and then tried completely removing the  `if(noProp ...)` condition, and I still can only get this to execute 1 time per page load. I'm stuck, any other ideas?

Comment: Only that something must be detaching the event handlers, or that the inputs/selects get replaced, or that something destroys jQuery. Can you give me a url so I can see the whole thing?

Comment: Style is off, just threw it up so you could see it. I can change if necessary.. [link](http://www.bingetech.com/calc/)

Comment: Try moving the four statements `var noProp = ...`, `var noTimesInsp = ...`, `var timeCompile = ...`, `var rateManager = ...` inside the `calculations()` function. Otherwise the values are read only once.

Comment: OK, I've edited the answer to reflect those four statements. Also, you might like to consider changing the `div` containers that receive the calculation results, to `span`. Divs are block elements while spans are inline.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something lke this:

```
$(function(){
    calculations = function($this){
        if($this) alert($this.val())
    }
    $('body').on('blur', 'input[type=text]', function(){
        calculations($(this));
    });

    calculations();
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2BtU/)